# How to hide particle system overlays

Tags: particles

I am trying to preview my project before making the final render, but there's a little box around every single grass particle that I added, and they're *very* annoying; does anybody know how to hide them?
[image]

I'm talking about these gray boxes on the ground.
Here's another picture:
[image]

Comment: It looks like just a bounding box display that will not show up in the final render. I would check visibility settings and viewport display settings on the involved objects.

Comment: You're correct, it won't; but I discovered what was wrong, I just had to click on "show overlays", a button next to show gizmos.

Comment: Oh good. Please add this as the correct answer yourself to avoid this popping up in the unanswered sections. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what was wrong, I just had to click on *Show Overlays*, a button next to *Show Gizmos*.